# How to fetch OTP from brower extension for Jmeter Script

Tags: jmeter

My Application requires an OTP for Login along with username and password.Authenticator extension in the browser generates OTP which is valid for 30 seconds. I need the OTP in the Jmeter script, what are the ways to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can integrate JMeter with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) so you will be able to kick off a real browser with the extension installed, get the OTP from there, store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and use that variable in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. It might also be the case there is a Java-based library for generating the OTPs like [`java-otp`](https://github.com/jchambers/java-otp), if it produces the same OTP as the browser extension you can put the .jar to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and generate the OTPs from the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using Groovy language
3. And last but not the least, presence or absence of the OTP-based login doesn't make a lot of difference for the load testing so you can ask developers/devops/whoever can do this to temporarily turn off the OTP login so you can focus solely on your application